# How to turn a fraction into a percentage? What is 1 / 1140 in a percentage?

Tags: probability, education

My question says, **A volunteer group is holding elections for President, Secretary, and Treasurer.  If there are 20 people in the group what is the probability that Sam, Isaac, and Luke are the ones chosen?**

My work so far is,
3C3 = 1, so there is only one way that Sam, Isaac, and Luke are the ones chosen for the President, Secretary, and Treasurer.

20C3 = 1140, so there are 1140 different ways to pick the President, Secretary, and Treasurer from a group of 20.

P (S, I, L all chosen) = 3C3 / 20C3 = 1 / 1140 
But I'm stuck here because I don't know how to simplify the fraction  1 / 1140 into a percentage and I don't know if my work so far is correct.

Comment: It is as simple as $1\div1140\times100\%$.

Comment: Why does it need to be written as a percentage anyways?  $\frac{1}{1140}$ is a perfectly acceptable way to present a probability.  So is $\approx .00087719\cdots$ and neither of these are intrinsically "better" or "worse" than representing it instead as $\approx 0.087719\%$.  Recall, a probability is always between $0$ or $1$, or equivalently between $0\%$ and $100\%$.  Recall also that $1 = 100\%$ and you can always multiply by one (*or equivalently multiply by $100\%$*) and it not change the meaning of the result.

Comment: I would think that your teacher expects you to do this using a calculator

Comment: Frankly, in many introductory probability questions involving counting, when I was teaching and grading assignments I very much *preferred* receiving the answers unsimplified with binomial coefficients and the like.  I would have *preferred* the answer of $\dfrac{\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$ to any of the other ways of representing the answer, as this usually directly implies what the thought process was of the person who came up with the answer.  Of course, you should do what your teacher asks you to, but unless specified don't assume that simplifying is always best.

Comment: As for the probability question... yes your answer of $\frac{1}{1140}$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It won't always be a finite decimal, like $\displaystyle \frac{5}{8}=0.625=62.5\%$.

In this case, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1140}=0.000\overline{87719298245614035}$, but we can just round to $0.0008772$, or $0.08772\%$.